# disbale xml button in android

Tags: android, xml, schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <string android:enabled="false" name="Close">Close</string>
    <string android:visable="false" name="Create">Create</string>
</resources>
```

i just added android:enabled="false" to my string .. and still i can't click the button

Comment: You can't put enabled or disabled on a string resource.  You can do that for xml drawables in a statelist drawable, but not strings.

Answer (score 0):

(You can't put enabled or disabled on a string resource.)

Here is an example of how to enable and disable a button

```
Button mybutton= findViewById(R.id.button);

// To disable the button
mybutton.setEnabled(false);

// To enable the button
mybutton.setEnabled(true);
```

You can enable or disable as in the previous example.

Or you can show and hide the button

```
Button mybutton= findViewById(R.id.button);

// To hide the button
mybutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// To show the button
mybutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```